# manipulate the words of a file by an array filled with words (retrieved from a file)

Tags: c

I browsed the file with `fgets`.
I tokenise the sentence returned by `fgets` with `strtok` to retrieve the words
I saved the words in a array of `char*`

```
while (fgets(chaine, TAILLE_MAX, fichier) != NULL) {
    chainetoken = strtok(chaine, " ");
    while (chainetoken != NULL) {              
        tableau[i] = chainetoken;
        chainetoken = strtok (NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }// it works wel
}
printf("%d \n", i);
```

Now, I want to go through the array of `char*` (`tableau[i]`) that contains the words of the file in order to find a word entered by the user and find the 2 words that precede and follow it in the file

```
printf("words to find?\n");
scanf("%s", mot_recherche);

for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    printf ("tableau %d.mot %s \n", i, tableau[i]); //tableau[0]=last word of the file
    if (strcmp(mot_recherche, tableau[i]) == 0)
        printf("this word exist \n");
} //doesn't work,it save only the last word of the array(of the file)!!!!
```

Comment: I think this is a simple typo. In you second loop use tableau[j] not i.

Comment: yes,thanks but it still does not work, i remove the if condition strcmp, i just did a print of  tableau[j] but the words are wrong

Answer (score 2):

You have three errors

1) in

```
while (fgets(chaine, TAILLE_MAX, fichier) != NULL) 
{
   chainetoken=strtok(chaine," ");
   while (chainetoken != NULL)
   {              
      tableau[i]= chainetoken;
      chainetoken = strtok (NULL," ");
      i++;
    }// it works wel
}
```

you need to save a *copy* (*strdup*) of the result of *strtok*, else you always save a pointer pointing inside *chaine* which is modified by each *fgets*

2) the separators for *strtok* must be " \n", else '\n' is part of the result returned by *strtok*

3) in

```
for (j=0; j<i; j++)
{
  printf ("tableau %d.mot %s \n",i,tableau[i]);//tableau[0]=last word of the file
  if (strcmp(mot_recherche,tableau[i])==0)
    printf("this word exist \n");
}//doesn't work,it save only the last word of the array(of the file)!!!!
```

you look at the entry *i* rather than *j* of *tableau*

Additional remark : in the *while* you need to check if *i* reach the number of entries in *tableau* else you take the risk to write out of it.

---

(edit to explain why it is needed to duplicate the result of strtok)

Having that program using *strtok* as you (without the duplication) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * fichier = fopen("in", "r");

  if (fichier != NULL)
  {
#define TAILLE_MAX 32
    char chaine[TAILLE_MAX];
    char * chainetoken;
    char * tableau[16];
    int i = 0, j;

    while ((fgets(chaine, TAILLE_MAX, fichier) != NULL)  &&
           (i != sizeof(tableau)/sizeof(tableau[0])))
    {
      chainetoken=strtok(chaine," \n");
      while (chainetoken != NULL)
      {              
        tableau[i]= chainetoken;
        chainetoken = strtok (NULL," \n");
        i++;
      }
    }
    fclose(fichier);

    for (j = 0; j != i; ++j)
      printf("'%s'\n", tableau[j]);
  }
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra f.c
/tmp % cat in
1234 5678
1 23 45 678
/tmp % ./a.out
'1'
'45'
'1'
'23'
'45'
'678'
```

the expected result is to see `1234 5678 1 23 45 678` but this is not the case and only the contains of the second line of `in` is correct (because it is the last line of the file).

*strtok* returns sub-strings of *chaines* modifying it to add null char each time it return a non null pointer, so (I indicate below the null character by a '@')

- *fgets* reads the first line, chaine_ contains "1234 5678\n@"
- *strtok* replaces the space in "1234 5678\n@" by the null char and returns the address of *chaine* ("1234@5678\n@") being memorized in `tableau[0]`
- *strtok* replace the '\n' by the null char and returns *chaine + 5* ("5678@") being memorized in `tableau[1]`
- the next next call of *strtok* returns the null pointer
- *fgets* reads the next line and modify *chaine* to contain "1 23 45 678\n@"
- *strtok* replaces the space after '1' by the null char and returns the address of *chaine* ("1@23 045 678\n@") being memorized in `tableau[2]`
- *strtok* replaces the space after '3' by the null char and returns *chaine + 2* ("23@45 678\n@") being memorized in `tableau[3]`
- *strtok* replaces the space after '5' by the null char and returns *chaine + 5* ("45@678\n@") being memorized in `tableau[4]`
- *strtok* replaces '\n' by the null char and returns *chaine + 8* ("678@") being memorized in `tableau[5]`
- *strtok* return the null pointer

so now *chaine* contains "1@23@45@678@" and the pointers in *tableau* are :

- tableau[0] = *chaine* = "1@23@45@678@", printf produces '1' rather than '1234' expected
- tableau[1] = *chaine + 5* : "45@678@", print produces 45 rather than '5678' expected
- tableau[2] = *chaine* : "1@23@45@678@", printf produces '1'
- tableau[3] = *chaine+2* : "23@45@678@", printf produces '23'
- tableau[4] = *chaine+5* : "45@678@", printf produces '45'
- tableau[5] = *chaine+8* : "678@", printf produces '678'

this is why it is needed to duplicate the result of *strtok* :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * fichier = fopen("in", "r");

  if (fichier != NULL)
  {
#define TAILLE_MAX 32
    char chaine[TAILLE_MAX];
    char * chainetoken;
    char * tableau[16];
    int i = 0, j;

    while ((fgets(chaine, TAILLE_MAX, fichier) != NULL)  &&
       (i != sizeof(tableau)/sizeof(tableau[0])))
    {
      chainetoken=strtok(chaine," \n");
      while (chainetoken != NULL)
      {              
        tableau[i]= strdup(chainetoken);
        chainetoken = strtok (NULL," \n");
        i++;
      }
    }
    fclose(fichier);

    for (j = 0; j != i; ++j) {
      printf("'%s'\n", tableau[j]);
      free(tableau[j]); /* to avoid memory leak */
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra f.c
/tmp % cat in
1234 5678
1 23 45 678
/tmp % ./a.out
'1234'
'5678'
'1'
'23'
'45'
'678'
```

Comment: strtok() will split the already allocated memory used by chaine into multiple strings by inserting nulls and in this case I don't think a strdup() call is needed, the tableau array will work perfectly well as pointers into chaine.

Comment: @Jackson you are wrong, the next call of `fgets(chaine, ...)` will rewrite _chaine_ so the previously saved pointer into _chaine_ will point to a modified contains

Comment: Good point. I missed the while loop. Doh. I think this means it time I switched of and went to bed.

Comment: Seeing as how you asked.

Comment: SorryI did not understand what you meant "you need to save a copy (strdup) of the result of strtok, else you always save a pointer pointing inside chaine which is modified by each fgets" I'm a beginner!!

Comment: @B.Ser I edited my answer to show why the duplication is needed